# Sumifs in Merge Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

```
A   B   4,93,906
    C   803
    D   84.80
    E   99%
A   B   4,93,906
    C   803
    D   84.80
    E   99%
```

Consider A in both cases merged. I need to use a formula like this:
`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"A",B:B,"B")`, when I use this I get answer 987812,
but when use
`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"A",B:B,"C")` I get answer 0.

Is there any way to get this answer?

Answer (score 1):

When cells are merged, the value is set to the topleft cell, the other cells are considered empty. You need to take this into account while writing formulae for merged cells.